# Changing a user's role via dropdown and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a site where the User model has a `role_id` attribute. There are currently three roles in the Roles table:

```
ID    NAME
1     user
2     manager
3     admin
```

In the admin section of the site, there is a table with a list of users. What I'm trying to do is to have a dropdown menu for each user where the user's role can be changed with an ajax request. This dropdown also needs to have its possible values dynamically populated based on the available roles. For example, if a `foobar` role is added later, the dropdown menus should reflect that.

The back-end part *seems* straight-forward enough: write a `change_role` method in the UsersController (with `before_action: is_admin`) and have it handle the ajax request inside a `respond_to` block. I'm just trying to figure out how to construct the front-end in a clean way, using Rails helpers and Unobtrusive JS (remote: true). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example. WARNING: this includes no error handling, which I advise you build in yourself based on your application. It also assumes you know how to wire up the routes, etc. You might want to get the `users_path` dynamically in your JS. look into `gon` gem for more information about that.

#### app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee

```
$(".role-select").on "change", ->
  user_id = $(this).data("user-id")
  role_id = $(this).val()

  $.post "/users/#{user_id}/update_role", 
         role_id: role_id
```

#### view

```
<select class='role-select' data-user-id={user.id}>
  [...]
</select>
```

#### controller

```
def update_role
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update(role_id: params[:role_id])
      # manage return status here
      head :ok
    end
  end
end
```